# Nigerian Olympiad

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are integers satisfying $ab + cd = 44,ad - bc = 9.$
Find the minimum possible value of $a² + b² + c² + d².$

Comment: It is common at this site to show, what one has tried so far. Usually questions of the type: Please solve this problem for me aren't received well.

Comment: Sorry for this question I used the AM-GM inequality and got 88. I'm not sure if it's correct because I didn't use the ad-cd=9

Comment: Note that this leads to $d\mid 9$ and from $ab+ad=53$ to $a\mid 53$. In the finitely many cases, you can solve the system for the remaining unknowns $b,c$ and check if they are integers

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, how do you get d | 9 so quickly? You have d(a-c) = 9, thus you have either d = 9, a-c = 1 or d = 3, a-c = 3 or d = 1, a-c = 9 and so on, (if I didn't overlook something. It looks to me like one has still quite some work to do through the different cases until one gets solutions that actually fit the equations.)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: As Cardioid_Ass_22's answer shows, $(a,b,c,d)=(0,-9,1,44)$ is a solution. But $d$ does not divide $9$. (Edited to add: I see now that the question was edited. So I assume your comment was valid when you posted it.)

Answer (score 11):

$$(ab+cd)^2=44^2\implies a^2b^2+2abcd+c^2d^2=44^2$$

Similarly:

$$a^2d^2-2abcd+c^2b^2=9^2$$

So:

$$a^2b^2+a^2d^2+c^2d^2+c^2b^2=44^2+9^2=2017\implies(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)=2017$$

$2017$ is prime so one of $a^2+c^2$ or $b^2+d^2$ is $1$ and the other is $2017$. Assume $a^2+c^2=1$. Then one of $a$ and $c$ is $0$ and the other is $\pm 1$. If $a$ is $0$, then  $d=\pm 44$. Then, $b^2=2017-d^2=9^2$.

So $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=0^2+9^2+(\pm 1)^2+44^2=2018$$

You can exchange $a^2+c^2$ and $b^2+d^2$ w/o l.o.g. (and $a$ and $c$ or $b$ and $d$).

Comment: And in fact this is the only possible value (not just the minimum possible value).

Comment: This is beautiful. Thanks

Comment: > `a2+c2 or b2+d2 is 1 and the other is 2017`. Now just sum.